# Django 2.3: Struggling to have form send email with an attachment. Not sure how files should be treated/ handled using FormView

Tags: html, django, python-3.x, file-upload, django-forms

OK so I am attempting to create a form on my website that will take input from a user. The fields include first_name, last_name, email, and then a file upload form that should take their resume. Unfortunately I cannot get this program to send an email that includes any document I attach. I am using FormView with django in order to handle the incoming information which seemed straightforward until it came time to handle a file. What i've seen from various other answers is that you'd use something like request.FILES['resume'] but that seems to be if you aren't using formview. I've been struggling with this for over 10 hours and would really love to have someone point me in the right direction.

forms.py:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from templated_email import get_templated_mail
from django.conf import settings
class UploadResumeForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
            'type':'text',
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'First Name',
            }), 
        required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
            'type':'text',
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Last Name',
            }), 
        required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
            'type':'text',
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Email',
            }), 
        required=True)
    resume = forms.FileField(widget=forms.FileInput(
            attrs={
            'name': 'resume',
            'placeholder': 'Resume',
            'class':'file-path validate',
            }), 
        required=False)
    class Meta:
        title = 'Resume Upload'

    def send_message(self, email, first_name, last_name, file):
        email_obj = EmailMessage(
            subject=f'Resumed Uploaded by {first_name} {last_name}!',
            body = f'''\nYou received a resume upload from {first_name} {last_name} at {email}.  
                    \nPlease follow-up.  
                    \nThank you,
                    \nSSG''',
            from_email=email,
            to=['me@gmail.com'],
            reply_to= ['me@gmail.com'])

        # try:
        attach_name = file.name
        print(file.name)
        # except Exception:
        #   print('No resume attached')
        #   pass
        try:
            attach_content = file.open().read()
        except Exception:
            # attach_content = file.getvalue()
            print("no file attached")
            pass
        try:
            attach_mimetype = mimetypes.guess_type(attach_name)[0]
            email_obj.attach(attach_name, attach_content, attach_mimetype)
        except Exception:
            print("no file attached")
            pass
        try:
            email_obj.send()
        except Exception as e:
            print(type(e), e.args, e)
```

views.py:

```
class CandRegisterView(FormView):
    template_name = 'website/candidate_register.html'
    form_class = UploadResumeForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if form.is_valid:
            # form = UploadResumeForm(request.POST, request.FILES )
            email_addr = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            first_name = form.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
            last_name = form.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
            file = form['resume']
            # form.cleaned_data.get('resume')
            form.send_message(email_addr, first_name, last_name, file)
            return HttpResponse('Your information has been sent. Thank you!')
        else:
            return form.errors
```

candidate_register.html

```
<form method= "POST" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}

                <fieldset>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i></span>
                      {{form.first_name}}
                      <!-- <input type="text"  class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" name={{form.first_name}}> -->
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i></span>
                      {{form.last_name}}
                      <!-- <input type="text" name="last_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name"> -->
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope"></i></span>
                      {{form.email}}
                       <!-- <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email"> -->
                    </div>
                  </div>  

                  <label>Uploading your resume allows us to add your information to our database. In the future, if a role opens up that fits your interest, we can reach out immediately and begin the interview process.</label>
                  <label>We will not disclose your resume to any clients without your consent.</label>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <form class="md-form" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="file-field">
                      <div class="btn btn-primary btn-sm float-left">
                        <span>Choose file</span>

                        <!-- <input type="file" name="resume"> -->
                      </div>
                      <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                        {{form.resume}}
                        <!-- <input class="file-path validate" type="text" placeholder="Upload your file"> -->
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
```

Not sure if this helps at all but my development.py (settings) file where all variables are stored in a .env:

```
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = config('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = config('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
    AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = config('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
    AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

    AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
    AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None

    STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'static'
    AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
        'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
    }
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.StaticStorage'
    STATIC_URL = 'https://%s/%s/' % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, STATICFILES_LOCATION)
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/img'),
        )
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
    # STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

    PUBLIC_MEDIA_LOCATION = 'media'
    MEDIA_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{PUBLIC_MEDIA_LOCATION}/'
    MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'
    DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.MediaStorage'
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media/photos')
    import dj_database_url 
    prod_db  =  dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
    DATABASES['default'].update(prod_db)
```

I can get the emails to send it just won't attach any documents that I attach. I included my aws settings because I am receiving all of my static files from AWS just fine but I don't know if when something is uploaded if it first needs to be uploaded to s3 and then attached to an email and sent off. I haven't really messed with getting the media files up on s3 yet but I have a feeling that it isn't configured properly which may be why the emails never have anything attached. I also feel like the documentation does a very poor job of discussing how to create forms with file uploads.

In the end, what I want it to do is to take in the users information and shoot an email to me and my team so that we are notified that someone put their information in. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what happened with all these different attempts? Of course, you can't know, because you have cleverly *caught all the exceptions and hidden them*. Don't do that. Remove the try/excepts and let Django tell you what is going wrong.

Comment: I should have uncommented on that line. it was uncommented and it still did nothing. The exceptions didn't kick any errors.

Comment: I appreciate your help. i had a nested form in my html that was causing the problem. I was attahcing something to a form that went nowhere. Once I removed that it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

OK so I am an idiot and didn't realize I had a form within another form. I removed the secodn form tag (which was where my upload resume form was) and then I also had never imported mimetype. Some of this code was provided by someone else on stack overflow and I was unaware that mimetype was something that needed importing. This is the first time I've dealt with file uploads so it was a little new to me. The next thing I was doing wrong was I was trying to use request.FILES['resume'] rather than form.cleaned_data.get('resume') in my views. Once I fixed these different things, it started to work.

here is my updated forms.py:

```
    def send_message(self, email, first_name, last_name, file):
        email_obj = EmailMessage(
            subject=f'Resumed Uploaded by {first_name} {last_name}!',
            body = f'''\nYou received a resume upload from {first_name} {last_name} at {email}.  
                    \nPlease follow-up.  
                    \nThank you,
                    \nSSG''',
            from_email=email,
            to=['me@gmail.com'],
            reply_to= ['me@gmail.com'])


        attach_name = file.name
        try:
            attach_content = file.open().read()
        except Exception:
            attach_content = file.getvalue()
        attach_mimetype = mimetypes.guess_type(attach_name)[0]
        email_obj.attach(attach_name, attach_content, attach_mimetype)
        try:
            email_obj.send()
        except Exception as e:
            print(type(e), e.args, e)
```

my views.py:

```
class CandRegisterView(FormView):
    template_name = 'website/candidate_register.html'
    form_class = UploadResumeForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if form.is_valid:
            # form = UploadResumeForm(request.POST, request.FILES )
            email_addr = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            first_name = form.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
            last_name = form.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
            file = form.cleaned_data.get('resume')
            # form.cleaned_data.get('resume')
            form.send_message(email_addr, first_name, last_name, file)
            return HttpResponse('Your information has been sent. Thank you!')
        else:
            return form.errors
```

my candidate_register.html file:

```
              <form method= "POST" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}

                <fieldset>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i></span>
                      {{form.first_name}}
                      <!-- <input type="text"  class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" name={{form.first_name}}> -->
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i></span>
                      {{form.last_name}}
                      <!-- <input type="text" name="last_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name"> -->
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope"></i></span>
                      {{form.email}}
                       <!-- <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email"> -->
                    </div>
                  </div>  
          <!--         <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" name="" type="submit" value="Submit">
                </fieldset>
              </form> -->
<!--               {% if messages %}
                <ul class="messages">
                    {% for message in messages %}
                    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
                {% endif %} -->
                  <label>Uploading your resume allows us to add your information to our database. In the future, if a role opens up that fits your interest, we can reach out immediately and begin the interview process.</label>
                  <label>We will not disclose your resume to any clients without your consent.</label>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <!-- <form class="md-form" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data"> -->
                    <div class="file-field">
                      <div class="btn btn-primary btn-sm float-left">
                        <span>Choose file</span>


                      </div>
                      <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                        {{form.resume}}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  <!-- </form> -->  (THIS IS WHERE I WENT WRONG! DONT ACCIDENTALLY NEST A FORM)
                </div>
```

Thanks for the help everyone!